# Sorting from smallest to largest, based on a value inside a class

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a class:

```
Class A
{
    List<double> count;
    List<Parts> parts;
}
```

where the `count` and `parts` coincide (meaning count[i] corresponds to parts[i], and so on).

When I sort my `count` from smallest to biggest using:

```
count.Sort();
```

How do I go about rearranging my `parts` List such that `count[i]` still corresponds to `parts[i]`?

Comment: Implment IComparer interface

Comment: Keep them in 1 list, such as `Tuple<Part, double>` or custom class.

Comment: Don't have 2 lists. Have a single list of a new type with members for count and part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to wrap those to in a seperate class for this. If every `Part` has a `count` then do something like this:

```
class PartWrapper
{
    public Parts parts { get; set; }
    public double count { get; set; }
}
```

If you now want to order ir by anything, you could just take your `List<PartWrapper>` and do something like this:

```
var parts = new List<PartWrapper>() { /* store data in it */ };
parts = parts.OrderBy(x => x.count).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I hit submit by tabbing one time too much

Comment: Another approach would be using the List's `Sort` method with a custom `Comparison<T>` implementation...for the coding enthusiasts

Comment: Or just add the count / stock / ... property directly into the `Parts` class.

Comment: probably you mean `parts = parts.OrderBy(x => x.count).ToList();` in the last line

Comment: Thanks, missed that one.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather implement a class

```
  public class PartCount: IComparable<PartCount> {
    public Parts Parts { get; set; }
    public Double Count { get; set; }
    ...

    public Boolean CompareTo(PartCount other) {
      if (Object.RefeenceEquals(null, other))
        return 1;

      return Count.CompareTo(other.Count);
    }
  }
```

You initial class will be changed into

```
  Class A {
    List<PartCount> parts;
  }
```

And you can sort as you want:

```
  // Just sorting, no Linq  
  parts.Sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had to keep them as two separate lists, you could use IEnumerable.Zip to associate the two and then sort:

```
var items = new A()

// populate A
...

var sorted = items.parts.Zip(items.count, Tuple.Create)
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Item2)
                         .ToList();
items.count = sorted.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
items.parts = sorted.Select(x => x.Item2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
class A
{
    List<double> count;
    List<Parts> parts;
    void Sort() {
        var result = from item1 in count.Select ((value, index) => new {value, index})
            from item2 in parts.Select ((value, index) => new {value, index})
                where item1.index == item2.index
            orderby item1.value
            select new {Count = item1.value, Part = item2.value};

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var x in result) {
            count [i] = x.Count;
            parts [i] = x.Part;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not best way)

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier you can put count also as a property in Parts class.Then you can sort a list of parts like

```
parts.sort((p1, p2) => p1.count > p2.count)
```

or

```
parts.OrderBy(p => p.count)
```